# Manual stepping in python for

Tags: python, for-loop

In C++, I can do this:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; ++i ) {
    if( something ) i += 3;
}
```

How can I do the same in Python?

```
for i in range(10):
    # ????
```

Comment: Due to lack of keywords for my problem, I could not find any related questions.

Comment: why do you need to do that ? usually this construct is not actually necessary(and there is almost always a better alternative)... if you really and truly need that you will need to do a while loop

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Just to make it clear. I know how to do a C-style for in python, I was wondering if with the construct `in range(10)` it would be possible to do extra stepping. Because I find the `while` approach ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python for loops work on iterators. If you run on an iterator object that you have bound to a name, you can make the loop skip future values by calling `next` yourself:

```
it = iter(iterable) # create our own iterator

for i in it: # loop on it
    # do stuff with i

    if something:
        next(it) # discard the next three values
        next(it)
        next(it)
```

You can of course use the return values from the `next(i)` calls, if you want. This can be handy for some kinds of text data files, where one header line specifies the meaning of the next few data lines.

You should be aware though that if you reach the end of the iterable sequence, `next` will raise a `StopIteration` exception. If that happens in the `for` loop's iteration, it takes care of the exception for you, but if it happens when you call `next` yourself, it will not be. If an unexpected end of the data is not an unrecoverable error, you will probably want to use a `try`/`except` block to suppress the exception.

Comment: Every answer here is a good answer, but I am marking yours as accepted because it actually avoids using C-style for.

Comment: Should not be next(it)?

Comment: @AndréPuel: Yes, you're right. I've fixed that silly mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The basic equivalent in Python is this:

```
for i in range(start, stop, increment):
    do_something(i)
```

That means that the following codes behave identically:

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i -= 2) {
    doSomething(i);
}

for i in range(10, 0, -2):
    do_something(i)
```

Normally, we want to start at zero, increment by one, and stop at a certain number, which leads to the shortcut:

```
for i in range(stop):
    do_something(i)
```

If you want to modify 'i', and have it affect how many times you loop, you must use a 'while' loop:

```
i = 0
while i <= 10:
    if (something):
        i += 3
    i += 1
```

...which is what you should also be doing in C++. A 'for' loop is for repeating a definite number of times. If you're modifying the counter inside the loop, then the loop is no longer definite and you should be using a while loop instead, since it's semantically a better fit.

Answer (score 2):

```
i=0
while i<10:
    if something:
        i += 3
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: I think you would need i=1 to start with since he is incrementing it before entering the loop

Comment: I think ++i and i++ doing the same just at the last line in loop

Comment: @JoranBeasley [Nope](https://eval.in/138860)

Comment: ahh you might be right ... I havent messed with C for a long time ... :P (+1 :P )